# Trouble with Java File I/O

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to write Strings to files in Java.

Basically, I'm supposed to read from a file containing text (assumed to be strings). For each line of text,
if the String has the format word1 word2 (that is, if it's two words), I have to write it to one file (a list of names), whereas if it doesn't have that format, I have to write it to another file, which is supposed to be called System.out (with the extension .txt)

I've got the list of names part working just fine. The names get written to the output file as they should, but when writing to the System.out file, only one line gets written.

So the lines formatted like regular sentences ("This should not be written", etc) get skipped. I'm not sure why this is. Here's some excerpts from my code:

```
public static void processData(BufferedReader inputFile, PrintWriter outputFile)
    {

        // A modified version of
        // the algorithm shown
        // on the class page.

        String inputLine = null;

        try
        {
            // While loop that processes
            // each line taken from the file.
            // First it checks whether the 
            // line has the format word1 word2

            while ((inputLine = inputFile.readLine()) != null)
            {               

                // Splits the line into tokens,
                // taking the delimiter to be
                // anything that is not an
                // upper or lowercase letter
                // or the tab character (\t)
                // in groups of at least one
                // (using the regex [^a-zA-Z]+)

                String[] tokens = inputLine.split("[^a-zA-Z\t]+");

                // REMOVE LINES 215-216
                System.out.println("inputLine is: " + inputLine);
                System.out.println("The length of tokens is: " + tokens.length);

                // If the line has the format
                // word1 word2, the outputWriter
                // method is invoked to process
                // the words and write them to
                // the output file

                if (tokens.length == 2){
                    outputWriter(tokens, outputFile);
                }

                // Otherwise, the systemWriter
                // method is invoked to write
                // the line to the System.out file

                // REMOVE LINE 234
                else{
                    System.out.println("ENTERED SYSTEMWRITER TREE AT: " + inputLine);
                    systemWriter(tokens);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be splitting with a space, like this:

```
String[] tokens = inputLine.split(" ");
```

This will make an array of words, which I think is what you want.